# Space evenly with flex-box

Tags: css, flexbox

bellow is a code snippet. What I'm trying to do is to get the li to have the same height inside each ul.
A responsive solution is required since we are targeting mobile devices.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container">
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 7</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 1 flex item 1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 5 flex item 5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 7</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 2 flex item 2 flex item 2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 6 flex item 6 flex item 6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">flex item 7 flex item 7 flex item 7</li>    
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-container { 
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background-color: Yellow;
}

.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-container:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: Orange;
}

.flex-container:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: Red;
}

.flex-container:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: Silver;
}

.flex-item {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: DeepSkyblue;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/szpali76/ufj35bzL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that it's not possible, because you try to align elements in different sub-containers. You could only spread all available list items vertically across each list (see Callum's answer), which is not what you want, if I understand correctly.

Is this just a hypothetical example, or are tables an option? Tables are still perfectly valid if the content *is* semantically in a table form. From what I can see in the example, this could be a valid case for a table, but it's hard to tell if you don't know what the actual intended content is going to be.

Comment: Yeah that's the main problem the content length is usually different, what suggested Callum helps me to stretch the list content, but what I trying to do is to have something like a table or a grid. Maybe a table is required here.

Answer (score 1):

if you're aligning the flex-items with column you can use the     `justify-content:` property to arrange them,

to see what I mean try adding:

.flex-container {
    justify-content: space-around;
    }

**[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/ufj35bzL/10/)**

Comment: Still, the LIs do not have the same height, as requested.